# SQL Server : duplicate select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have data in a table like this:

```
no  name
---------
41  name1
41  name2
41  name3
41  name4
41  name5
41  name6
41  name7
41  name8
41  name9
41  name10
```

And I want to come up with a SQL statement that will return this result. A record type of top and bottom for every five records.

```
no  name    REC_TYPE
--------------------
41  name1   top
41  name2   top
41  name3   top
41  name4   top
41  name5   top
41  name1   bottom
41  name2   bottom
41  name3   bottom
41  name4   bottom
41  name5   bottom
41  name6   top
41  name7   top
41  name8   top
41  name9   top
41  name10  top
41  name6   bottom
41  name7   bottom
41  name8   bottom
41  name9   bottom
41  name10  bottom
```

I tried this query but it only duplicates the records.

```
SELECT 'top' AS REC_TYPE, * 
FROM table

UNION

SELECT 'bottom', * 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your union query is doing the required duplication, what you need is to get the data in the correct order, we could use the row_number function to order the rows as the following (considering that you are depending on the name column to order your data):

```
SELECT no, name, REC_TYPE
FROM
  (
   SELECT 'top' AS REC_TYPE, no, name  
   FROM table_name
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'bottom', no, name  
  FROM table_name
  ) t
ORDER BY (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY no, REC_TYPE ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(name, 'name','') AS INT))-1) /5, 
         REC_TYPE, 
         CAST(REPLACE(name, 'name','') AS INT)
```

Here, I used `CAST(REPLACE(name, 'name','')` to get the correct order of names, for your real data, you may simply order by name.

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CHv12JUt)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define how rows are ordered in a unique way. It can be by combination of columns or date. In my example, I am ordering them by identity column.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable;

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    No INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO #TempTable (No, Name)
VALUES
(41, 'name1'),
(41, 'name2'),
(41, 'name3'),
(41, 'name4'),
(41, 'name5'),
(41, 'name6'),
(41, 'name7'),
(41, 'name8'),
(41, 'name9'),
(41, 'name10');
```

First, we need to separate the rows in group:

```
WITH DataSourceGroups AS 
(
    SELECT * 
         ,IIF((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) % 5  = 0, 1, 0) AS [GroupID]
    FROM #TempTable
)
SELECT *
      ,SUM([GroupID]) OVER (ORDER BY id) as [GroupID]
FROM DataSourceGroups
```

[image]

I am using `ROW_NUMBER` to order the rows again (as for example there might missing `ID`s values in my table because of deletion.

Then, just join the static data depending on your desire output:

```
WITH DataSourceGroups AS 
(
    SELECT * 
         ,IIF((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) % 5  = 0, 1, 0) AS [GroupID]
    FROM #TempTable
)
SELECT No
      ,Name
      ,[GroupName]
FROM
(
    SELECT Id
          ,No
          ,Name
          ,SUM([GroupID]) OVER (ORDER BY id) as [GroupID]
    FROM DataSourceGroups
) DS
INNER JOIN 
(
    VALUES (1, 1, 'top')
          ,(2, 1, 'bottom')
          ,(3, 2, 'top')
          ,(4, 2, 'bottom')
) StaticDS ([GroupOrderID], [GroupID], [GroupName])
    ON DS.GroupID = StaticDS.GroupID
ORDER BY [GroupOrderID], ID
```

[image]